# Unmixedness Theorem of Macaulay

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

I am trying to read Matsumura and Monsky's [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/kyoto-journal-of-mathematics/volume-3/issue-3/On-the-automorphisms-of-hypersurfaces/10.1215/kjm/1250524785.full) on the automorphism groups of hypersurfaces, and I don't understand the following part on page $3$.

Let $f(X)$ be the defining homogeneous polynomial of our hypersurface, and $f_i(X) $ partial derivative of $f$ with respect to the $i$'th component.
We have $(f, f_{0}, \cdots, f_{n+1})=(f_{0}, \cdots, f_{n+1})$ using the Euler identity and by the assumption of non-singularity of our hypersurface this ideal has zero depth. 
We define $\mathfrak{a}_i=(f_{0}, \cdots, \hat{f}_{i}, \cdots, f_{n+1}), 0 \leq i \leq n+1$ by omitting $f_i$, and see that this has depth $1$. 
Now it says, "It follows from this and from the unmixedness theorem of Macaulay that
$\mathfrak{a}_{i}: f_{i}=\mathfrak{a}_{i} .$ "

I see that the unmixedness theorem is about heights of associated primes of $R/I$ for an ideal $I$ of a Noetherian ring. However, I cannot see how to apply it in this case to get the above result. Can someone fill in the details?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You omitted to tell us what depth is. Here *depth* means coheight, so the coheight of $\mathfrak a_i$ equals 1, and therefore its height is $d$, where $d$ is the number of variables minus 1. If $f_i$ is a zerodivisor on $\mathfrak a_i$, then it belongs to an associated prime. It follows that  this prime contains $(\mathfrak a_i,f_i)$ whose height is $d+1$, a contradiction with unmixedness of $\mathfrak a_i$.

In order to prove that $\mathfrak a_i$ is unmixed notice that its height equals its number of generators. But its height equals its grade, since we are in a polynomial ring over a field, which is a Cohen-Macaulay ring, so $\mathfrak a_i$ can be generated by $d-1$ elements that form a regular sequence. (In fact, its generators, being homogeneous, form a regular sequence.) So $R/\mathfrak a_i$ is Cohen-Macaulay.